# Flash and HTML5 the Fallback?

Tags: flash, html, html5-video, fallback

Is it possible to have Flash video first then to fall back to html5?

Like I have something like this if(Flash is installed){ run flash player} else if(can do video tag w/ h.264){ use HTML5 video tag with h.264}

Now this is javascript so it's being written in javascript, then the inner html will get the right tags.

Answer (score 1):

This is just my opinion, but I think you'd be better off switching the fallback order: HTML5 video with a fallback to Flash. Flash [market penetration is so high](http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/version_penetration.html) that I doubt any visitors to your site would ever experience the arguably better HTML5 video delivery. Plus, it would be much easier to implement as scripts like [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/) have already been written to handle such fallbacks. This is just my two cents, but hopefully it's helpful.

Comment: Depends on personal preference, really. I'm 100% behind the video tag over Flash, though I will concede that things like true full screen (not just full-window) video and ease of switching between HD and non-HD sources is still something Flash handles better.

Answer (score 0):

you can find a javascript flash detection tutorial [here](http://www.prodevtips.com/2008/11/20/detecting-flash-player-version-with-javascript/). Or a plugin that will meet your needs (if I read wright) [here](http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using Flash as a fallback to HTML5 video, as Andrew describes: http://henriksjokvist.net/archive/2009/2/using-the-html5-video-tag-with-a-flash-fallback

I tend to agree with Andrew regarding switching the fallback order, but if you really want Flash first, you could always reverse the logic as described in the above linked example.